# prevent specific file change by windows update?

Tags: backup, windows-registry, windows-update, remote-desktop

Did a hack to enable concurrent rdp sessions and windows update always overwrites the dll. Windows update apparently takes ownership of the file, how can I prevent that and keep the file unchangeable?

And what is the best way to identify registry keys I should backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can configure windows update to ignore selected files. You can disable windows update by turning off Windows update and the background intelligent transfer service.

You will then be able to update windows manually by downloading each KB update and running the installer off line. Kind off a pain to do it.

I would recommend backing up the entire windows operating system instead of selected keys because unless the keys didn't have dependencies in other sub key, it would be difficult to restore.

Comment: inevitably I end up doing a system restore, even though I have updates turned off. Apparently the update is already downloaded and eventually it ends up installed